# Accessing an ArrayList method, when the ArrayList is inside an object

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

I am trying to design a text based game.

The game will have a feature in which, if the user inputs ***get all***, all the objects in the room must be added to the player's inventory.

The inventory of the player is an ArrayList of objects and so is the room's object "*sack*"

The code that i have written is as follows:

```
public void getAll(Room room, Player player)
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < room.objectNames.size(); i ++)
      {
          player.inventoryObjects.add(room.objects.get(i));
      }
  }
```

This method is inside the main class, i.e , the class which has the main method.

The arraylists are declared as:

```
public ArrayList<Objects> inventoryObjects = new ArrayList<Objects>();
//this is in the Player Class

public ArrayList<Objects> objects = new ArrayList<Objects>();
//this is in the Room Class
```

Can you tell me an alternative to line: 3 in the first piece of code that i have typed(the one with the loop) ?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The [`addAll` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) will perform the loop for you.

```
player.inventoryObjects.addAll(room.objects);
```

Comment: so, is using 2 "**.**"s allowed ? Sorry for asking this question, but please do excuse me as i am a beginner.